# How to divide 60 mins datapoints into 15 mins?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with every 60 mins interval value. Now, I want to divide them into 15mins interval using the averages between those 2 hourly values. How do I do that?

```
Time                 A                    
2016-01-01 00:00:00  1  
2016-01-01 01:00:00  5  
2016-01-01 02:00:00  13
```

So, I now want it to be in 15mins interval with average values:

```
Time                      A      
2016-01-01 00:00:00       1
2016-01-01 00:15:00       2   ### at 2016-01-01 00:00:00 values is 1 and
2016-01-01 00:30:00       3   ### at 2016-01-01 01:00:00 values is 5. 
2016-01-01 00:45:00       4   ### Therefore we have to fill 4 values ( 15 mins interval ) 
2016-01-01 01:00:00       5   ### with the average of the hour values.
2016-01-01 01:15:00       7
2016-01-01 01:30:00       9
2016-01-01 01:45:00       11
2016-01-01 02:00:00       13
```

I tried resampling it with mean to 15 mins but it won't work ( obviously ) and it given `Nan` values. Can anyone help me out? on how to do it?

Comment: Did you try resample with interpolate?

Comment: you are not calculating means but inputing missing values with a linear approximation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just resample: `df.resample("15min").interpolate("linear")`

As you have the column `Time` set as index already, it should directly work

Comment: Sorry for the late upvote and acceptance. Thanks for the help:D!

Answer (score 3):

We can do this in one line with `resample`, `replace` and `interpolate`:

```
df.resample('15min').sum().replace(0, np.NaN).interpolate()
```

**Output**

```
                        A
Time                     
2016-01-01 00:00:00   1.0
2016-01-01 00:15:00   2.0
2016-01-01 00:30:00   3.0
2016-01-01 00:45:00   4.0
2016-01-01 01:00:00   5.0
2016-01-01 01:15:00   7.0
2016-01-01 01:30:00   9.0
2016-01-01 01:45:00  11.0
2016-01-01 02:00:00  13.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time': ["2016-01-01 00:00:00", "2016-01-01 01:00:00", "2016-01-01 02:00:00"],
    'A': [1 , 5, 13]
})
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
new_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=df['Time'].iloc[0], end=df['Time'].iloc[-1], freq='15min')
df2 = df.set_index('Time').reindex(new_idx).interpolate().reset_index()
df2.rename(columns={'index': 'Time'}, inplace=True)
print(df2)
#                  Time     A
# 0 2016-01-01 00:00:00   1.0
# 1 2016-01-01 00:15:00   2.0
# 2 2016-01-01 00:30:00   3.0
# 3 2016-01-01 00:45:00   4.0
# 4 2016-01-01 01:00:00   5.0
# 5 2016-01-01 01:15:00   7.0
# 6 2016-01-01 01:30:00   9.0
# 7 2016-01-01 01:45:00  11.0
# 8 2016-01-01 02:00:00  13.0
```

If you want column `A` in the result to be an integer you can add something like:

```
df2['A'] = df2['A'].round().astype(int)
```